# Add an extra value to array

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have below code

```
   $result = array();
   $category_name = array();
   foreach($category as $cat) {
     $category_name[] = $cat->category_name;  // I would like to add this value to result array
     $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
     foreach($campaigns as $campaign) {
          $result[] = $campaign;
     }
   }
```

I would like to add this value ($cat->category_name;) to `$result` array when doing `foreach` loop. How can I do that ?

Comment: then do  `$result[] = $cat->category_name;`

Comment: Thanks @DevsiOdedra. But that is creating another element in `$result[]` array. I would like to do that inside `foreach` loop so that I can get the value when iterate `$result[]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like:

```php
   $result = array();
   $category_name = array();
   foreach($category as $cat) {
     $category_name[] = $cat->category_name;
     $result2 = array();
     $result2[] = $cat->category_name;
     $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
     foreach($campaigns as $campaign) {
          $result2[] = $campaign;
     }
     $result[] = $result2;

   }
```

Or:

```php
   $result = array();
   $category_name = array();
   foreach($category as $cat) {
     $category_name[] = $cat->category_name;
     $result2 = array();
     $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
     foreach($campaigns as $campaign) {
          $result2[] = $campaign;
     }
     $result[$cat->category_name] = $result2;

   }
```

Then for the second example you can do:

```php
foreach ($result as $category_name => $campaigns) {
  ... // $campaigns is a list here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arusekk. But that is creating another element in $result[] array. I would like to do that inside foreach loop so that I can get the value when iterate $result[]. Thanks.

Comment: Is that what you wanted to get?

Comment: Thanks @Arusekk. But later I am doing this `@foreach( $result as $spc ) {//some code}`. How can I get the `category_name` when I am iterating ?